# session_start() al retornar a index no muestra sesión activa

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Cuando ingreso las credenciales del usuario  en la pagina `índex.php` al dar iniciar sección la información es validada en el archivo `validación.php` en el cual se crea la sesión y retorna con la función `echo "<script> window.location.replace('index.php') </script>";`a la pagina inicial, misma que en ves de mostrar los campos para ingreso de usuario debería mostrar los datos de la sesión activa pero no lo hace, es como si al retornar del archivo `validación.php` la sesión fuera cerrada.

**Nota:** Se que la validación en la base de datos con las credenciales ingresadas son correctas y de echo al ejecutar `echo "secion activa ". $_SESSION['usuario'];` muestra que el usuario que ah iniciado dicha sesión, pero  al momento de retornar al índex al parecer la sesión no se mantiene activa.

**index.php**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Insercion de registros</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>
<body>
<?php
require 'validation.php';
?>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Inicio <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="index.php">Clientes <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        </ul>
        <form action="validation.php" method="post">
            <?php
            if (isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) { ?>
                <br>
                <div class="form-group text-right">
                    <?php echo $_SESSION['usuario']; ?>
                    <a href="cerrar_sesion.php" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Cerrar sesión</a>
                </div>
            <?php } else {
                ?>
                <div class=" form-group text-right">
                    <div class="form-group"></div>
                    <form action="">
                        <input type="text" name="usuario" value="" PLACEHOLDER="Usuario">
                        <input type="password" name="password" PLACEHOLDER="Contraseña">
                        <button type="submit" name="enviar" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Ingresar</button>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">Registrarse</a>
                    </form>
                </div>
            <?php }  ?>

        </form>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <h3>Elija el típo de cliente</h3>
            <select class="form-control" name="razon_social" id="option_tipo">
                <option value="n/a">Seleccione una opción</option>
                <option value="natural">Natural</option>
                <option value="juridico">juridico</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            <div id="formulario">
                <div class="alert alert-warning">Por favor el tipo de solicitud que deséa registrar!</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**validation.php**

```html
<?php
require 'conexion.php';


if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
    $usuario = htmlentities(addslashes($_POST['usuario']));
    $password = htmlentities(addslashes($_POST['password']));

    if (!$usuario == null && !$password == null) {
        $go = new validation();
        $go->validate($usuario, $password);

    } else {
        echo "<script>alert ('Verifique los datos');</script>";
        echo "<script> window.location.replace('index.php') </script>";
    }
}


class validation
{
    private $connection;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $con = new conexion();
        $this->connection = $con->getConnection();
    }

    public function validate($user, $pass)
    {
        try {
            $statement = $this->connection->prepare("select * from login where usuario=:usuario and password=:password");
            $statement->execute(array(':usuario' => $user, ':password' => $pass));
            if ($statement->rowCount() != 0) {
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['usuario'] = $user;
                echo "secion activa ". $_SESSION['usuario'];

                //echo "<script> window.location.replace('index.php') </script>";
            } else {
                echo "<script>alert ('El usuario no existe');</script>";
                echo "<script> window.location.replace('index.php') </script>";
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Error al ejecutar la consulta" . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: me parece que es porque en el index.php no tienes declarado el session_start() al inicio de la pagina.

Comment: jaja eso a sido , no puedo creer que estuve media hora dando vueltas al asunto  sin hallar la solución, :( errores de novatos muchas gracias por tu tiempo un saludo ..

Comment: me parece que debiste sugerirle a @OmarMiranda que colocara como respuesta para que le dieras los puntos y la aprobacion de el y no darle los puntos a otro que simplemente se baso en la respuesta de el.

Comment: @OmarMiranda coloque la respuesta .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Errores

1.- [`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.session-start.php) debe ser llamada antes de enviar cualquier otra cosa al navegador, pero al archivo `validation.php` lo estás incluyendo despues del `<body>` y ya has enviado cosas al navegador (todo el `HTML` anterior).

2.- Ejecutas `session_start` solo cuando válidas los datos enviados por `POST`, es decir, que la sesión nunca se vuelve a recuperar ya que nunca más fue inicializada.

### Soluciones

1.- Deberías mover el `<?php require 'validation.php'; ?>` antes del `<!DOCTYPE html>`

**index.php**

```
<?php
require 'validation.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
...
```

2.- `session_start` crea un archivo temporal (*depende del tiempo de vida que sea indicado*) en el servidor lo cual es contraproducente si se tiene demasiadas visitas. Una forma de iniciar sesión solo cuando se ha validado un usuario es utilizar [`session_name`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.session-name.php).

**validation.php**

```
<?php
define('PUBLIC_SESSION_NAME', 'cliente');// Nombre de la COOKIE para la session.

// Función helper para iniciar sesión 
function startSession() {
    session_name(PUBLIC_SESSION_NAME);
    session_start();
}

// Validamos que previamente exista la cookie de la sesión 
if (isset($_COOKIE[PUBLIC_SESSION_NAME])) {
    startSession();
}

require 'conexion.php';
//.....
            startSession();// <-- Usamos la función para inicia sesión 
            $_SESSION['usuario'] = $user;
            echo "secion activa ". $_SESSION['usuario'];
//....
```

Answer (score 2):

Intenta como dice el amigo Omar Miranda, colocarlo al inicio del archivo `index.php`

```
<?php session_start() ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Declara el `session_start()` en el index para que permanesca activa ademas de no olvidar ponerlo en toda la navegavilidad del sistema.